# Is this shape definition an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I want to define an ellipse-like shape with two radii. The radius at 0 degrees is 3. The radius at 90 degrees is 2. But in order to close the loop, we have to specify some smooth transition between them.

If the transition is linear (radius at 45 degrees is 2.5), does that make it an ellipse?

**EDIT:** "Linear" means the radius decreases linearly from 3 to 2 as the angle increases linearly from 0 to 90 degrees. So the equation is r = 2 + t/90 for quadrant 1.

"The angle" means the angle made by the positive x axis and whatever radius we're looking at, centered at the origin. The loop I'm describing is also centered at the origin.

Comment: Convert $r=-\frac{2}{\pi}\theta+3$ to Cartesian and see what you get.  Or just [graph it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D-2*t%2Fpi%2B3).

Comment: Or perhaps you were looking for a plot more like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+Piecewise%5B%7B%7B-2*t%2Fpi%2B3,+t+%3C+pi%2F2%7D,+%7B2*t%2Fpi%2B1,+t+%3E+pi%2F2%7D%7D%5D,+%7Bt,+0,+pi%7D%5D).  But either way, you can see it's not an ellipse.

Comment: @Bye_World The second one. I thought it would be symmetric in the 4 quadrants just like a circle and ellipse are. Interesting, tho. I thought my linear transition would be smooth.

Comment: Your linear transition is smooth from $0^\circ$ to $90^\circ$, but not smooth *at* $90^\circ$ when it jumps from decreasing to increasing. As an analogy, think of a [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to define an ellipse centered at origin is
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$
where $a$ is the horizontal semi-minor axis, and $b$ is the vertical semi-minor axis.

You often see this written parametrically as
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = a \cos(t) \\
y(t) = b \sin(t) \end{cases}$$
with $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$, but it is important to notice that $t$ is **not** an angle here. If we use $P = (x(t), y(t))$, $O = (0, 0)$, and $A = (1,0)$, the angle $\angle AOP$ is actually $\theta$,
$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{b \sin(t)}{a \cos(t)}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\tan(t)\right)$$
i.e. $\theta$ is the angle from positive $x$-axis counterclockwise to the point. Conversely,
$$t = \arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\tan(\theta)\right)$$

In the circle case, $a = b = r$, and we have $t = \theta$, so for circles,
$$\begin{cases}
x(\theta) = r \cos(\theta) \\
y(\theta) = r \sin(\theta) \end{cases}$$
is true.

---

If we assume the angle is measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis as usual, then you could use
$$\frac{x^2}{3^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

In general, we can also describe the same ellipse as a function of $x$, by solving equation $\eqref{1}$ for $y$:
$$y(x) = \pm \frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3^2 - x^2}$$

At 45° from origin (center of the ellipse) we have $y = x$, and the distance to the center is $$r(45°) = \sqrt{x^2 + (y(x))^2} = \sqrt{\frac{2 a^2 b^2}{a^2 + b^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{72}{13}} \approx 2.3534$$

So, if your shape has $r(45°) = 2.5$, it is not an ellipse.

Comment: You can think of that $\;t\;$ as an angle, why not? Of course, it is **not the angle** *you mean*..! To write "the angle" can be highly confusing and misleading: what **the** angle do you mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio: $t$ is a parameter which ranges from $0$ to $2 \pi$. It is not any angle.

Comment: It is an angle if I want to think of $\;t\;$ that way. Observe that many times students are taught, since high school, to think of variables over which the trigonometric functions apply as angles. It certainly is not **the** angle you meant in your answer...but I still can't understand why you and MvG think it should be.

Comment: @DonAntonio: $t$ is not an angle! There are no points or lines or anything else that make an angle $t$ with anything else! Just because $t$ has a range of $0$ to $2\pi$, or $-\pi$ to $\pi$, or $0°$ to $360°$, or $-180°$ to $+180°$, does not mean it is an angle. It is just a parameter that happens to have **angular units**. Do you call your tape measure **an inch** or **a centimeter** because it has subdivisions with those units marked on it? If you do, you're wrong.

Comment: When people like me use mathematics as a tool, and not a topic of investigation in itself, terms like *angle* and *parameter* (and *vector* and *scalar* and *units* and *scale*) have to be precise, or the results are garbage. I do know that many teach applied math by dropping all units, and working with the numbers only, but that just leads to probes crashing on other planets rather than landing on them. [Dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) is important, and calling parameters *angles* because they happen to have angular units is horribly misleading.

Comment: @No I don't agree with you at all: I am a pure mathematics researcher and lecturer, and my terms are as precise and clear as possible within the limits of the knowledge (or lack of) of the education level of the OP and others. Calling $\;t\;$ *an angle*, in this context and in this question, within the logical parameters I already mentioned, is as precise and clear as you can expect anything else to be.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Calling $t$ an angle is as correct as calling the product of the distance between New York and Los Angeles and the mass of the Eiffel Tower divided by five minutes, momentum. You can argue that it is valid because the units match. It does not change the fact that doing so is nonsense. I pity the people who have to suffer with the results of your students' work. You, sir, should seriously consider the real-world effects of your teaching.

Comment: You should better try to chill out: it is going to affect your angles, in the real world or in the much better and much cozier mathematics world.

Answer (score 1):

Try the usual parametrization of an ellipse with radius $\;3,2\;$ :

$$r(t)=\left(\,3\cos t,\,2\sin t\,\right)\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi$$

and  we get

$$r\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\left(\frac3{\sqrt2}\,,\,\,\frac2{\sqrt2}\right)\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\left\|\,r\left(\frac\pi4\right)\,\right\|=\sqrt{\frac92+2}=\sqrt\frac{13}2\approx2.55$$

which is pretty close to what you want...though I'm not sure what you call "the transition" to, and even less what does it mean that is linear.

Comment: I suggest you stress the fact that $t$ is a parameter that happens to look like an angle, but isn't really the angle in the sense of polar coordinates.

Comment: @MvG I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "...in the *sense* of polar coordinates". Any point on the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}9+\frac{y^2}4=1$$ is given **in polar coordinates** by the equation I wrote above, for some definite value of $\;t\in[0,2\pi]\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: $t$ is not the angle $(3 \cos t, 2 \sin t)$ makes with origin and the positive $x$ axis.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Nobody said it was: that is obviously the arctangent of the quotient of the $\;y\;$ by the $\;x\;$ entries...I don't really understand why you and MvG think this may cause trouble or misunderstandings to the OP...though perhaps it can. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: What @NominalAnimal wrote is what I was aiming for, too. The angle between a point and the positive $x$ axis is the angle I'd be using for a polar coordinate description, and your parameter is something else. Obvious to me, but not neccessarily the target audience of this question, thus my suggestion to stress that. So yes, nobody said it would be that angle, but imo you didn't say loudly enough that it's not that angle.

Comment: @MvG Thanks for the input. What still is unclear to me why you, and perhaps also NominalAnimal, think I should have stressed this...But I suppose that y now that should be clear to anyone, and also to the OP.

Comment: "Linear" means the radius decreases linearly from 3 to 2 as the angle increases linearly from 0 to 90 degrees. So the equation is r = 2 + t/90 for quadrant 1. Will edit OP. Also, I don't follow this debate over t not an angle. This post says 0 ≤ t ≤ 2π which seems to imply that it **is** an angle from 0 to 360 degrees. Finally, I'm not sure this post gives an answer. Are you saying my OP indeed defines an ellipse? Or my definition is not an ellipse?

Comment: @DrZ214 No, your post does *not* define an ellipse as was already pointed out elsewhere. I didn't really understand that "linear" thing and I only tried to give an idea on how to achieve an ellipse by means of well known formulae, which also fulfill *almost* your condition that at $\;t=\pi/4\;$ you get a vector of length $\;2.5\;$ ...that's all. There is not ellipse, as far as I am aware, whose radius increases/decreases "linearly" in the sense you seem to mean.

Answer (score -1):

The principal radii of curvature are

$$ \frac{a^2}{b}, \frac{b^2}{a} $$

By looking at the *ellipse evolute* center and radii of curvature positions close to that of evolute can be chosen for a smooth transition tangential junction find two profiled ellipse approximations of any eccentricity.

Sketches of  [EvoluteBasedEllipses](http://www.takayaiwamoto.com/Egg_Draw/Egg_String_Draw.html)